# MySql: Insert a row and get the content

Tags: mysql, insert

Is it possible to insert a row and get the values inserted in the same query?

Something like...

```
INSERT INTO `items` (`item`, `number`, `state`) 
(SELECT '3', `number`, `state` FROM `item_bug` WHERE `id`='3')
```

And then, get ID and execute a

```
SELECT * FROM `items` WHERE `id`='$id'
```

But using only one query.

Comment: Not sure if what you're asking can really be done in one DML query but I'm following this question to see if it can - it would be helpful to know.

Comment: What is wrong with two queries?

Comment: Nothing at all, except for the overload..

Comment: two queries is not atomic?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can call a stored procedure which will perform the insert and return a resultset in a single call from your app layer to mysql:

**Stored procedure call**

```
mysql> call insert_user('bar');
+---------+----------+
| user_id | username |
+---------+----------+
|       1 | bar      |
+---------+----------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)

$sqlCmd = sprintf("call insert_user('%s')", ...);
```

**Simple example:**

```
drop table if exists users;
create table users
(
user_id int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
username varchar(32) unique not null
)
engine=innodb;


drop procedure if exists insert_user;

delimiter #

create procedure insert_user
(
in p_username varchar(32)
)
begin
declare v_user_id int unsigned default 0;

 insert into users (username) values (p_username);

 set v_user_id = last_insert_id();

 -- do more stuff with v_user_id e.g. logs etc...

 select * from users where user_id = v_user_id;

end#

delimiter ;

call insert_user('bar');
```

Comment: It seems slower than use 2 mysql query, isn't it?

Comment: would jumping into your car and driving to the supermarket to buy bread then driving home, then driving back to buy milk be faster than driving to the supermarket and buying bread and milk ? One trip or two ?

Comment: @Ivan 2 query surely is easier

Answer (score 15):

Execute your insert statement and then you can do this:

```
SELECT * FROM `items` WHERE `id`= LAST_INSERT_ID()
```

Comment: @Quassnoi: Sorry if I wasn't clear. The expectation is that the OP executes the INSERT statement as given in the original question. I'll flesh out the answer better.

Comment: the original question asks for "insert a row and get the values inserted in the same query".

Comment: @Quassnoi: Which we both know cannot be done here. Hence I'm giving OP an alternative solution.

Comment: I have a feeling this might be the best way to do it, since PK is used, so in case of large tables it would be faster in the case of absent indices

Comment: Caveat: If you inserted different rows during the same session (as it happens with memory-persistent applications, such as Flask or Django with Gunicorn), you'll perhaps want to `ORDER BY \`id\` DESC LIMIT 1` that statement.

Answer (score 11):

No, it's not possible in `MySQL` (unlike `PostgreSQL`, `SQL Server` and `PL/SQL` in `Oracle`).

You will have to do it in separate queries.

Comment: And now [MariaDB-10.5+ with INSERT .. RETURNING](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/insertreturning/).

Answer (score 1):

**if you are using php then**

instead of this you can use

```
mysql_insert_id();
```

which will give the id of last inserted record.

The other data will be same as inserted.
Only id will change which you can get by `mysql_insert_id()`

So you do not need to run second query.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using multiple statements if you like to choose that route.  Firstly when you connect to your database make sure that multiple statements is set to true:

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: databaseHost,
    user: databaseUser,
    password: databasePassword,
    database: databaseName,
    multipleStatements: true
});
```

Then you can just define your sql as:

```
var sql = "your insert statement; your select statement";
```

Just separate individual statements using the semi colon.  Your select result will be results[1] in this example.