# Get value which was defaulted on insert

Tags: php, mysql

Let's take a simple table where one of the keys is a timestamp with default value set to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

Is there a way to get this generated timestamp after the insert? I need an analogical solution to [`mysql_insert_id`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) which you use with `auto_increment`.

Is that possible at all? I know it's not the safest practice, but to be honest I'm just curious at the moment. I already do it without using `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as a key - I just generate it in code and pass as a standard parameter.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5432756/223226

Comment: mpapec, what do you mean by that link? Which part of it answers my question?

Comment: You want values for inserted rows but only `mysql_insert_id` is available.

Comment: Ok, I thought that maybe something like `out` parameters is available (like in oracle) or something like that.

Comment: Switch to postgresql, it can return whole row after insert.

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion but not really possible in my case ;) I would really love to use other database engine

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php):

```
int mysql_insert_id ([ resource $link_identifier = NULL ] )
```

> Retrieves the ID generated for an AUTO_INCREMENT column by the
>   previous query (usually INSERT).

So `mysql_insert_id` works **only** on auto increment columns and you **cannot** have a datetime column with AUTO_INCREMENT as attribute, thus you cannot retrieve the timestamp of the last inserted row.

Instead you can do a separate query using the `mysql_insert_id` to fetch the last timestamp.

Comment: I know that, I just used mysql_insert_id as an example (analogy) of what I wanted to do. And your solution wouldn't work if I had a foreign key as a primary key + date as a second primary key.

Comment: @KeluThatsall Then that's a bad database design. If your second primary key is date, there's still a chance for it to repeat and thus, overall failing to uniquely identify a record.

Comment: @I Can Has Cheezburger I don't agree - every time where there are events stored in database it's a good practice to put (start)date as one of the keys. It's just probably not a very good idea to use DEFAULT_TIMESTAMP for that.