# Why are Laravel eloquent model attributes based on default definitions empty after save?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

With a very simple model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Example extends Model
{

}
```

And it's schema for completeness:

```
<?php

use App\Models\Lease;
use App\Models\Choice;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateTableExamples extends Migration {

    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('example', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->enum('status', [1, 2, 3])->default(1);
            $table->text('abc')->nullable();
            $table->text('foo')->nullable();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('example');
    }
}
```

Why does the following save statement, result in empty attributes for the fields that are defined with defaults?

```
$example1 = new App\Models\Example();
$example1->foo = "BAR";
$example1->save();

var_dump($example1->attributes);
```

This outputs the following, note that the output has skipped the status field. Also note that field `abc` is missing.

```
array (size=4)
    'foo' => string 'BAR' (length=3)
    'id' => int 19
```

If I reload the model, with `$example1->fresh()`, I get the expected output:

```
array (size=4)
    'foo' => string 'BAR' (length=3)
    'abc' => null,
    'status' => int 1,
    'id' => int 19
```

Is there a way to avoid the `fresh` method? Under the hood, fresh is another trip to the db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try to set the defaults in your Model additionally (or exclusively) as suggested in other posts: [How to set a default attribute value for a Laravel / Eloquent model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18747500/how-to-set-a-default-attribute-value-for-a-laravel-eloquent-model)

This works for me in a Laravel 5.1 installation:

```
class Example extends Model
{
    protected $attributes = [
        'status' => 1
    ];
}
```

However, if you consider your DB as the only source of truth (and are setting the defaults there), it might be safer to get a fresh instance from it. If you look into Eloquent's **save()** you will find that it does not fetch the updated/inserted record (and afaik, some databases as mysql do not support returning the record upon insert/update within a single call - [you might use a stored procedure though](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5432756/mysql-insert-a-row-and-get-the-content)).

Answer (score 0):

Eloquent Model has `getOriginal()` method which returns model's original attribute values.

Just tested it and it returns all columns with values. So it will be:

```
$example1 = new App\Models\Example();
$example1->foo = "BAR";
$example1->save();

var_dump($example1->getOriginal());
```

https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_getOriginal