# MySQL Get value inserted by trigger in Java

Tags: java, mysql, sql

Using MySQL, I have the following SQL Table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE books (
    author INT, 
    book INT, 
    name VARCHAR(128), 

    PRIMARY KEY(author, book)
);
```

What I want is that I have an Id for author that I set manually and an Id for book that is incremented for each author id. Therefore I created a trigger like so:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trBooks
    BEFORE INSERT ON books
    FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.book = (
    SELECT COALESCE(MAX(book), -1) + 1 FROM books
    WHERE author = NEW.author
    );
```

This works fine for me. But now I need to know the book id that was set for my inserted entry that I inserted in Java. Something like the `Insert` with `Output` as in `MSSQL` or a `Statement.executeQuery("INSERT ...")`. The solution has to be thread safe, so a separate `INSERT` and `SELECT` is no good solution, since there might have been another `INSERT` in the meantime.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: There are other ways to achieve thread safety

Comment: Don't use a trigger, but instead do the insert with a stored procedure, and let it find the new book number, so it can do the insert *and* return the number. E.g. see [MySql: Insert a row and get the content](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5432756/5221149).

Comment: @Andreas Wouldn't the trigger work with the procedure's insert or what's the reason for the `don't use the trigger`? But thanks for that, did not know about procedures.. These will be called with `Statement.executeQuery()` in Java?

Comment: Called using [`CallableStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html). The reason for replacing the trigger with the stored procedure is that the stored procedure needs to do the `SELECT MAX(book) + 1`, so it knows the value and can return it to the caller using an output parameter.

Comment: Ah of cause.. Thank you very much! This solved my problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data model just doesn't make sense.  You have two entities, "books" and "authors".  These should each be represented as a table.  Because a book can have multiple authors and an author can write multiple books, you want a junction table.

This looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Books (
    BookId INT auto_increment primary key,
    Title VARCHAR(255)
);

CREATE TABLE Authors (
    AuthorId INT auto_increment primary key,
    Name VARCHAR(255)
);

CREATE TABLE BookAuthors (
    BookAuthorId INT auto_increment primary key,
    AuthorId INT, 
    BookId INT, 
    CONSTRAINT fk_BookAuthor_BookId FOREIGN KEY (BookId) REFERENCES Books(BookId),
    CONSTRAINT fk_BookAuthor_AuthorId FOREIGN KEY (BookId) REFERENCES Authors(AuthorId),
    UNIQUE (AuthorId, BookId)
);
```

As for your question about inserts.  You don't need a trigger to set auto-incremented ids.  You can use `LAST_INSERT_ID()` to fetch the most recent inserted value.

Comment: I admit, I did not select the best example here. But I did not want to put my whole table here, so I used this example.

Comment: Does LAST_INSERT_ID() also work on Non-Auto-Increment fields? Like shown in my Example?

Comment: @WhiteStripes . . . No.  You can use `LAST_INSERT_ID()` to get the auto-increment primary key value of the row inserted, and then look up other values in that row.